# DataTables and Rails Setup But Showing No Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I've followed along with the following tutorials to get DataTables setup in my Rails app, but I am seeing no change. Here's what I followed:

https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

I am not getting an error. I'm just seeing no change. And I restarted my server.

Application.js

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

Application.css

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

View:

```
<table id="products">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Something</td>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Something</td>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Something</td>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Products.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#products').dataTable
```

I just want to be able to sort columns. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting Products.js.coffee back to regular javascript and seeing if the results are the same. If so, the problem is either with the javascript itself or the compilation of the coffeescript (make sure the coffee-rails gem is in the Gemfile). Also check out the [RailsCast Coffeescript Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/267-coffeescript-basics).

Comment: What do you mean by the statement: 'make sure the gem is there'? Is that a gem for coffeescript or is there another gem for datatables to make it work with coffeescript?

Comment: Yes, make sure coffee-rails gem is in the Gemfile. Also, at the end of the RailsCast/AsciiCast mentioned there are additional debugging tips. I updated the answer to make it more clear.